# Recursive generation of subsets is faster than iterative generation

Tags: c++, recursion, subset

I'm solving the following problem on the CSES Problem set.
[Apple Division](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1623)

I know as a rule iterative programs tend to run faster than their recursive equivalents however the following recursive solution outperforms its iterative counterpart.

Recursive Version:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
void s(int k, vector<long long int> &subset, vector<long long int>& v, long long int &m){
    const long long int sum = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0LL);
    const int n = v.size();
    if(k == n){
        long long int ssum = accumulate(subset.begin(), subset.end(), 0LL);
        m = min(m, abs(2*ssum-sum));
    }
    else{
        s(k+1, subset, v, m);
        subset.push_back(v[k]);
        s(k+1, subset, v, m);
        subset.pop_back();
    }
}
 
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<long long int> v(n, 0LL);
    for(auto &x: v) cin>>x;
    vector<long long int> subset{};
    long long int m = LLONG_MAX;
    s(0, subset, v, m);
    cout<<m;
    return 0;
}
Share c
```

Iterative Version:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<long long int> v(n, 0LL);
    for(auto &x: v) cin>>x;
    long long int sum = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0LL);
    long long int m = LLONG_MAX;
    for(int b = 0; b < (1<<n); b++){
        vector<long long int> subset{};
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(b & (1<<i)) subset.push_back(v[i]);
        }
        m = min(m, abs(2*accumulate(begin(subset), end(subset), 0LL)-sum));
    }    
    cout<<m;
    return 0;
}
```

According to the online judge, the iterative version takes about 0.26s on a case of size n = 20 vs the recursive which takes about 0.04s.

Any explanations?

Comment: Please don't use either ``#include<bits/stdc++.h>``  or ``using namespace std;`` and *especially* not at the same time.

Comment: I know it's bad practice to use both, in general. However I don't see the harm in writing it for the purpose of generating a quick solution, especially a single file that doesn't have to be merged into anything.

Comment: @Archimedesprinciple The issue of using that header is that if anyone wants to compile your code using a compiler such as Visual C++, they have to change that header to the proper ones.  If you know that the header is not standard, don't introduce it in a general C++ question when you could easily have provided the standard headers.

Comment: The second thing is this -- we have no idea, and maybe you don't either, how this "online judge" built your program or how it times your code.  If it built your program without optimizations, then the timing data is bogus.

Comment: Your recursive version creates one "subset" vector. The iterative version creates (and grows, and destroys) 1,048,576 of them.

Comment: you do not need to create a vector `subset` to accumulate certain elements of another vector. Thats unnecessary dynamic allocations and reallocations that isnt present in the recursive

Comment: `std::accumulate` is useful to accumulate elements that are in a container. Creating a container only to be able to call `std::accumulate` isnt efficient

Comment: @Archimedesprinciple *However I don't see the harm in writing it* -- The other issue is that it *can* be harmful to use both that header and `using namespace std;`, especially if your code uses `gcd`, `swap`, `data`, or any of those names as identifiers.  All of those identifiers are in the `std` namespace, and if you aren't aware of this, the code will generate very weird compiler errors.

Comment: weird compiler errors or calling the wrong function without being noticed. Especially in a "quick solution" such quirks can cost more time than they save